# Loop a range and skip rows in Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have an excel worksheet that accepts input from another excel file. This excel file has structured data in which I need to separate individually as sheets. I already have the following code to copy and format that data in a certain range but I need to loop this process for the whole worksheet until there's no more data.

The range currently I set is **A2:P20** the next range is 4 rows below and that would be **A25:P43**.

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Sub CopySheetToClosedWorkbook()
    Dim fileName
    Dim closedBook As Workbook
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet

    fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")

    If fileName <> False Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set currentSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
        Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open(fileName)

        closedBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:P20").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        closedBook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        closedBook.Close (True)

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        CopySheetAndRenameByCell2

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something based on the code below.  I have set the last row as 1000, you will need to derrive this from your data.

```
Sub SplitRangeTest()

Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lRangeSize As Long
Dim lSpacerSize As Long

lRangeSize = 19
lRow = 2
lSpacerSize = 4
lLastRow = 1000   ' Get the last populated row in the column of choice here

Do Until lRow > lLastRow

    Debug.Print Range("A" & lRow).Resize(lRangeSize, 16).Address

    lRow = lRow + lRangeSize + lSpacerSize

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: what does _Debug.Print Range("A" & lRow).Resize(lRangeSize, 16).Address_ do?

Comment: It shows the addresses of the ranges produced, you'd do your copying etc on this range.

Comment: I've managed to get it working now but it returns an empty row in the end and causes error. Do I need to adjust the _Do Until_ condition? The last row of my data is dynamic

Comment: You need to work out the last row.  I put a comment in the code and the answer notes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Sub CopySheetToClosedWorkbook()
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim closedBook As Workbook
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet

    fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")

    If fileName <> False Then
        start_row = 2
        rows_to_copy = 19
        row_step = 23

        Set currentSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
        Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open(fileName)

        last_row = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For y = start_row To last_row Step row_step
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input").Rows(y).Resize(rows_to_copy, 16).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Rows(y).Resize(rows_to_copy, 16).Value
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

it's worth mentioning here that you set `currentSheet` but don't actually use it. Also, you shouldn't really use `ThisWorkbook` like that. Maybe you should be using `currentSheet` instead (or at least, it's parent).